# What does the return value of removal of string from variable mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to check what the following code really did.

```
"resultant_value="${original_value%/*}"
```

It removes a pattern, '/*', from a variable, original_value.
To check the removal had happened I checked the return value of it, like following.

```
original_value=''
resultant_value="${original_value%/*}"
result=$?
echo "remove 1: result = ${result} : original_value = ${original_value}, resultant_value = ${resultant_value}"

original_value='../..'
resultant_value="${original_value%/*}"
result=$?
echo "remove 2: result = ${result} : original_value = ${original_value}, resultant_value = ${resultant_value}"
```

The outputs are following

```
remove 1: result = 0 : original_value = , resultant_value = 
remove 2: result = 0 : original_value = ../.., resultant_value = ..
```

Both return values are 0. It seems that return value from ${original_value%/*} does not care of removal of matched pattern or not.

What does the return value of removal of string from variable mean in Bash?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `$?` will be `0` for both cases.

Comment: @anubhava : thank you for commenting. I would like to know why both $? are 0. Or what $?=0 means in this context?. Is it related to removal of string from variable or not?

Comment: No, it is not related. `0` just means command executed successfully irrespective of any replacement made or not.

Comment: @anubhava : thank you again. If so, do I have a specific way to check the removal had happened or not? Or should I use another command like sed?

Comment: If you care that a removal happened, you actually care that the pattern matched. You can use a conditional expression inside `[[ ... ]]` to check that.

Comment: `sav_value=$org_value; res_value="${org_value%/*}"; if [[ "$sav_value" == "$org_value" ]]; then echo no substitution made on $org_value" ; exit 1 ; fi` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, the return value/exit status of a variable assignment statement is defined by [the following rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html):

> The text after the `=` in each variable assignment undergoes tilde
>   expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.
>
> If any of the assignments attempts to assign a value to a readonly
>   variable, an error occurs, and the command exits with a non-zero
>   status.
>
> If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit
>   status of the command is the exit status of the last command
>   substitution performed.  If there were no command substitutions, the
>   command exits with a status of zero.

Thus, of all different types of expansions only command substitution (`$(...)`) can affect the status of an assignment statement. Parameter expansions, including prefix/suffix removals, don't influence the return value in any way<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>*</sup> The only exception is the `${parameter:?error_message}` - **Display  Error if Null or Unset** version of parameter expansion *when used in an interactive shell* (in a non-interactive shell a failed expansion of this kind simply quits the shell).

Comment: Thank you for answering in detail. Please let me ask you the meaning of "of all different types of expansions only command substitution" in above answer. It sound contradictory because of words, all and only. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mora I meant, that when we consider all types of expansions, it turns out that only command substitution has this property.